# Django query parameters: MultiValueDictKeyError - Key not found in QueryDict

Tags: python, django

I have a simple webpage with a single link, `index.html`:

```
<a href='/dog/?owner=' + data['owner'] + '&breed=bulldog'>Dog</a>
```

Here data is passed dynamically via the server.  
`urls.py` has the method definition to call:

```
...
url(r'^dog/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='dog.html'),
        name='dog'),
    url(r'^ajax/dog/$',
        views.dog,
        name='ajax/dog'),
...
```

And my `views.py` has the method defined:

```
def dog(request):
  owner = request.GET['owner']
  LOG.info(owner)
  breed = request.GET['breed']
  LOG.info(breed)
  ...
```

I get the following error when I click the link in `index.html`:

```
...
  File "/mnt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 295, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'breed' not found in <QueryDict: {u'owner': [u'kevin_lawder']}>"
```

I'm really confused as to why one query parameter is present in the QueryDict dictionary and the other is not. I tried replacing `request.GET['breed']` with `request.GET.get('breed')` but that returns `None`. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: what does your browser's devtools tell you is being sent?

Comment: in the Template you have access the context like this
`{{ data.owner}}` and ommit double quote `"` around bulldog

Comment: @shourav omitting double quotes didn't help. I see the `owner` is printed correctly in the logs, the problem is while trying to access `breed` query param.

Comment: Try changing & to &#38;

Comment: You need to give some more details. Exactly how are you constructing that URL? That's not Django template syntax. Show the context of that URL code and exactly what data i passed to it.

Comment: @thebjorn that did it. I'm using jquery dataTables to render a list of _dogs_ and looking at the network logs I realized that the `AjaxSource` was set to `/ajax/dog/?owner={{ request.GET.owner }}` instead of `/ajax/dog/?owner={{ request.GET.owner }}&breed={{ request.GET.breed }}`. Thanks all for the help!